# How to read one value from an array PHP

Tags: php

I know its silly question but really I don't know whats wrong, I have class that retrieve an array of parameters,like this with print_r function

```
Array ( [0] => 
      Array ( [points] => 39930 
              [level] => 14 
              [base] => 32000 
              [next] => 40000 
              [progress] => 99 
              [platinum] => 30 
              [gold] => 112 
              [silver] => 290 
              [bronze] => 1050 
              [total] => 1482 ) )
```

so if I want specific value from this array I can write

```
$getCount = $psn->get_count($psnUser['jid']);
echo $getCount['gold'];
```

the output must be 112
but its show me blank page
what should I do?

Comment: please refer to the [PHP Manual on arrays](http://php.net/arrays) to learn how to access them. Also, make sure to enable error reporting.

Comment: Sorry fo being Silly, after submitting the question I saw my response is two dimeinsion array so I used echo $getCount [0]['gold']; which solved my problem.

Comment: Set your [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to ALL on your development server, and set your configuration to display errors - this will give you very useful debug information when developing. Remember to turn display errors off on your production server.

Comment: Read that to learn how to see errors: [Nothing is seen. The page is empty and white.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dealing with a multidimensional array, so you have to point at:

```
$getCount[0]['gold'];
```